# Furnace error 33. Limit switch tripping

Tags: furnace

Furnace runs for a few minutes, then limit switch trips when it reaches 32.5 celsius.
System worked before. No changes.

- Same happens without filter
- Vents are not blocked
- Cleaned heat exchanger
- Tested a second limit switch, same result
- Blower motor cleaned. Not loose. Running (slowly?)

I've ordered a replacement motor capacitor, coming in a week.

Also, I'm able to restart system by letting blower cool down, resetting switch, and power cycling.
Flames don't seem to be blowing back.

I'm running out of ideas.

Could the capacitor be the culprit?

Comment: Which limit switch? Heat exchanger temperature limit, or something else?

Comment: What make/model is said furnace?

Comment: Flame roll out switch. It’s a reset-able switch located beside the burner area, that trips at 32.5 degrees Celsius.

Comment: The make of the furnace is Bryant. I’m not sure where to find the model.

Comment: New information. I opened up a (duct side) cover around 8” in diameter between the heat exchanger and the  AC coil. Problem does not happen, as there is more airflow, which is what I’m trying to prove. Does this mean my blower is running slow???